¿Porque me responde con error 404 y página en blanco al usar gh-pages?
Resulta que estoy usando gh-pages para publicar un proyecto de React.
Tengo ciertos problemas a la hora de subir el proyecto.Me imagino que es por un problema de rutas. Me gustaría que me pudieran brindar una mano puesto que no veo el error.
¡Muchas gracias!
Error de consola : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
Repositorio Github: https://github.com/Chulyni/Formulario-de-contacto.git
Code Package.json :
{
  "name": "form-react",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "homepage": "https://Chulyni.github.io/Formulario-de-contacto",
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.2",
    "gh-pages": "^6.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "prettier": "^3.3.0",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.6.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}




Agrega la pieza de código donde crees que puede estar el problema, así como el nombre de los archivos involucrados, esta pregunta necesita ser mas especifica.

Agrega el nombre del proyecto en el enlace:
https://chulyni.github.io/src/main.jsx
https://chulyni.github.io/Formulario-de-contacto/src/main.jsx
